# python cross platform apps

Tags: python, webkit, cross-platform, packaging, py2exe

I'm trying to make an app in CPython that should work on both linux and windows.
I'm using the webkit library, witch works fine on linux (Ubuntu 12.04), but I can't get it to work on Windows.

I know that I can compile my app into a Windows executable *(.exe)* with `py2exe`, but to do that it must work on my Windows machine.

The question is: Is there any way I can package my app under linux, so it will have it's dependencies (webkit) bundled with it, so it will work under Windows? Or is there any way to make a windows executable that doesn't need any dependencies from a python file, under linux?

Thank you!

EDIT:
Here is my code for the test app:

```
import gtk
import webkit

class Base:
   def __init__(self):   
       self.builder = gtk.Builder()    
       self.builder.add_from_file("youtubeWindow.ui")       
       self.main_window = self.builder.get_object("main_window")
       self.scrl_window = self.builder.get_object("scrl_window")
       self.webview = webkit.WebView()
       self.scrl_window.add(self.webview)
       self.webview.show()  
       self.webview.open("http://youtu.be/o-akcEzQ6Y8") 
       self.main_window.show()

   def main(self):
       gtk.main()

print __name__
if __name__ == "__main__":
    base = Base()
    base.main()
```

Comment: What happens when you try to run on Windows? What is the error message you receive, if any?

Comment: when I try to run my script, it doesn't recognize "import webkit" (witch works on Linux). And I didn't have any luck finding a working webkit library for Windows

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok, so i couldn't get webkit to work on windows with GTK, but i found out that Qt provides an integrated WebKit module, so I donwloaded PySide (the Qt wrapper for python) and I tested it with this script:

```
import sys
from PySide import QtCore
from PySide import QtGui
from PySide import QtWebKit

class MainWindow (QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.setGeometry(300,300,800,600)
        self.setWindowTitle('QtPlayer')
        web = QtWebKit.QWebView(self)
        web.settings().setAttribute(QtWebKit.QWebSettings.PluginsEnabled, True)       
        web.load(QtCore.QUrl("http://youtu.be/Dys1_TuUmI4"))
        web.show()
        self.show()


def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = MainWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Also i used *GUI2EXE* and *cx_Freeze* to package it into an .exe windows app. (Don't forget to include the modules *atexit,PySide.QtNetwork*, more details [here](http://qt-project.org/wiki/Packaging_PySide_applications_on_Windows))

A cool guide on Qt-Webkit can be found [here](http://www.rkblog.rk.edu.pl/w/p/webkit-pyqt-rendering-web-pages/) (It usese PyQt, but it's compatible with Pyside)

Also a Pyside tutorial [here](http://zetcode.com/gui/pysidetutorial/)

Answer (score 0):

In order run your script on Windows you need to install Webkit and its bindings for Windows (libraries). The 2 links below provide the setup files and instructions.

http://opensourcepack.blogspot.com/2009/12/pywebkitgtk-windows-binary.html
http://opensourcepack.blogspot.com/2011/01/conservative-all-in-one-pygtk-installer.html

The second link provides a binary that installs all the needed libraries (a all-in-one package).

Comment: I installed **pygtk_aio-2011_win32_installer_py25-27-rev5.exe** from the second link. I can now import webkit and gtk, but when i run my app i get the error: _GtkWarning: Could not find the icon 'gtk-fullscreen'. The 'hicolor' theme was not found either, perhaps you need to install it.
  self.webview = webkit.WebView()_
The script works until i add **self.scrl_window.add(self.webview)** So i think theres a problem in the webkit lib